# Issue in installing Linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I am currently using Linux kernel 4.15.0.96 generic. Now I want to build Linux kernel from my fork of Linux GitHub repository.

In my fork I have added few include files. With help of online guides I managed to build the  kernel from my fork, and after installing on running command `uname -r` the output was correct and it showed new kernel version. But when I went to the folder `/usr/include/` my changed include files were not present, it had only previous files. Kindly help.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. There are no kernel-specific include files in `/usr/include/` - you will only find user-space libraries in there.

Comment: So where should I look for include files that I modified in my fork of Linux for importing them in my code.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do here. Where do you expect those changed include headers to end up after you install the kernel? Are you running [headers_install](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/headers_install.html)?

Comment: No I didn't run headers_install. can u share a guide/tutorial that can be helpful in building Linux kernel from sources and that explains all the details.

Comment: This time I have used the command headers_install but still there are old header files in  /usr/include/